# I need to show only month and year in date field TCA typo3

Tags: php, typo3-8.x

```
'construction_period_from' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:River/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:River.from',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
            'size' => 7,
            'eval' => 'date',
            'default' => time()
        ],
    ],
```

This is the tca field that I am using. By default the calendar is loaded in the backend. But I only need to show the month and year. In database the timestamp value is stored. is there any option in tca to show only month and year?

Answer (score -1):

You have to set format in **value** attribute of **TCA** text field.

```
<f:form.textfield property="tca" value="{newGirlfriend.birthDate->f:format.date(format:'m-d')}" />
```

I hope this will useful to you

Comment: i need it to implement in tca. i don't think fluid wiil help in this case.